# File Security in PHP And Deleting Files

Tags: php, laravel

I have a project in Laravel 5.1

And i have product pictures.

I want to delete picture files when i delete product in database.

**My image root is**

```
img/product
```

**I have versions of pictures**

```
public function getVersions()
{
    return [
        'large'     => '/large',
        'medium'    => '/medium',
        'small'     => '/small',
        'thumbnail' => '/thumbnail',
        'root'      => ''
    ];
}
```

**My product image root is**

```
$productImageRoot = public_path('img/product/'.$product_id);
```

I want to learn What is the best practice to delete all pictures in a secure way.

Here is my code for deleting all pictures of product.

```
/**
     * @desc Ürün resimlerini ve resimlerin bulunduğu klasörleri siler.
     * @param $product_id
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function deleteAllPictureFiles($product_id)
    {
        /**
         * Resim türlerinin klasör yollarını çekiyoruz.
         */
        $folderPaths      = $this->getVersions();

        $productImageRoot = public_path('img/product/'.$product_id);

        $pictures         = (new ProductPicture)->getAllPicturesOfProduct($product_id);

        try
        {
            /**
             * Resim yolu yazılabilir ise...
             */
            foreach($pictures as $picture)
            {
                /**
                 * Tüm resimleri siliyoruz.
                 */
                foreach($folderPaths as $folderPath)
                {
                    unlink($productImageRoot.$folderPath.'/'.$picture->picture);
                }
            }

            /**
             * Tüm klasörleri siliyoruz.
             */
            foreach($folderPaths as $folderPath)
            {
                rmdir($productImageRoot.$folderPath);
            }

            return TRUE;
        }
        catch(\Exception $e)
        {
            /**
             * Resim yolu yazılamaz ise hata dönderiyoruz.
             */
            throw new \Exception(trans('product.is_not_writable'));
        }
```

This code caused an error that paths is not writable.

Now it is the topic that i don't know exactly. I want to learn chmod options for files and folders. And what should i do during deletion ? What is the most secure way to delete files ? I don't want use chmod 777. I know it is not secure.

Comment: did you try using 775?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel to delete the directory much easiser.

```
File::deleteDirectory('img/product/'.$product_id);
```

Also you're right, don't use 777. 755 should work. If 755 doesn't work, but 777 is, the group is probably wrong and you could fix it with `chown -R youruser:yourgroup yourlaravelfolder`. Most likely your user and group will be the same.

Make sure to make a backup before attempting any of this though.